# Stack overflow exception error in a recursive function

Tags: c#

I just started learning c# however I have some experience with java, so one of the things I wanted to do is to generate a 2d array map filled with 1's and 0's and recursively check if there is a path without stepping on 1's.

However after writing the code and running it it shows me the stack overflow exception error.

Where did I do something wrong?

Edit: the end of the array(the cell with the largest value 9,9(it's a 10x10 array) in this case is set to 6 as the end point)

Code for the recursive method:

```
public static int recursiveCheck(int[,] grid,int x, int y, int finalX, int finalY, int paths)
        {
            if (grid[x, y] == 6)
            {
                paths++;
                return paths;
            }
            if ((grid[x + 1, y] != 1) && (x+1 < finalX))
                return recursiveCheck(grid, x + 1, y, finalX, finalY, paths);
            if ((grid[x, y+1] != 1) && (y+1 < finalY))
                return recursiveCheck(grid, x, y+1, finalX, finalY, paths);
            if ((grid[x - 1, y] != 1) && (x > 0))
                    return recursiveCheck(grid, x - 1, y, finalX, finalY, paths);
            if (grid[x, y - 1] != 1 && y >0)
                    return recursiveCheck(grid, x, y - 1, finalX, finalY, paths);
            return 0;
        }
```

Array Initialization code:

```
public static int[,] gridGen()
        {
            int[,] grid = new int[10, 10];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int lim;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    lim = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                    //Console.WriteLine($"lim: {lim} ");
                    grid[i, c] = lim;
                }
            }
            grid[0, 0] = 2;
            grid[grid.GetLength(0) - 1, grid.GetLength(1) - 1] = 6;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                    Console.Write(grid[i, c] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            return grid;
        }
```

Comment: You said the array is filled with 1s and 0s but your function only exits when it encounters a 6. Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I set the 9,9 cell of an array to 6(it's a 10 by 10 array)

Comment: Funnily enough `StackOverflowExceptions` are caused by the stack filling up.. the prime candidate for this are to many recursions, either because its endless and wrong, or its just too deep. i think you want to convert this to a queue instead

Comment: Do you think you could add the initialization code for the grid?

Comment: And the calling code to please?

Comment: @TheGeneral Hm? I heard about queue's in java but didn't really work with them. The reason I went with recursion is because I did something similar already but with only 2 directions. How would I go about using the queue?

Comment: On a first glance the code should never end as there is no tracking of visited points... Not exactly sure how your Java equivalent version works...

Comment: Queue based loop, instead of calling itself, it places the data in the queue, and process that path next, so on and so forth

Comment: Though i think your logic is just wrong either way, you need to debug this and see why its never ending

Comment: What's your initial input?

Comment: Your method is tail recursive, meaning that it is easy to convert to a loop. In the loop you’ll never get a stack overflow exception, although you may end up with an infinite Loop, which is probably almost as bad.

Comment: Remember that every recursive function needs to have the same structure: (1) if we're in a base case, return without doing any recursion, (2) if we're not in a base case, recursively solve one or more **smaller problems**, (3) combine the solutions of the smaller problems and return the solution.  You are failing to meet the requirement of step two that every recursive case be *a simpler problem* than the current problem.

Comment: If the subject of pathfinding in C# interests you, you might want to read the series I did on my blog about it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/astar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not keeping track of which spaces you've already visited. So supposing your grid has two zeros right next to each other, your function will move to one in the first level of recursion, then to the other in the second level, then back to the first in the third level (even though the first level of recursion is still on the stack) and so forth forever.

There are a number of ways that you could keep track of where you've already visited. If you're willing to modify the input array temporarily when this method is called, you could just set the space you're currently on to `1` before looking at the ones around it.

```
    public static int recursiveCheck(int[,] grid,int x, int y, int finalX, int finalY, int paths)
    {
        var originalValue = grid[x, y];
        if (originalValue == 6)
        {
            paths++;
            return paths;
        }
        grid[x, y] = 1; // prevent deeper recursion from coming back to this space
        if ((grid[x + 1, y] != 1) && (x+1 < finalX))
            return recursiveCheck(grid, x + 1, y, finalX, finalY, paths);
        if ((grid[x, y+1] != 1) && (y+1 < finalY))
            return recursiveCheck(grid, x, y+1, finalX, finalY, paths);
        if ((grid[x - 1, y] != 1) && (x > 0))
                return recursiveCheck(grid, x - 1, y, finalX, finalY, paths);
        if (grid[x, y - 1] != 1 && y >0)
                return recursiveCheck(grid, x, y - 1, finalX, finalY, paths);

        grid[x, y] = originalValue; // allow other path checking to revisit this space.

        return 0;
    }
```

Also note that you can probably simplify things a little bit by turning the recursion upside down a little: do your boundary checks and wall checks as exit criteria right away, and use the number of paths purely as a return value rather than an input.

```
public static int recursiveCheck(int[,] grid, int x, int y, int finalX, int finalY)
{
    if(x < 0 || x > finalX || y < 0 || y > finalY)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    var originalValue = grid[x, y];
    if (originalValue == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (originalValue == 6)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    grid[x, y] = 1; // prevent deeper recursion from coming back to this space
    var paths = recursiveCheck(grid, x + 1, y, finalX, finalY)
        + recursiveCheck(grid, x, y + 1, finalX, finalY)
        + recursiveCheck(grid, x - 1, y, finalX, finalY)
        + recursiveCheck(grid, x, y - 1, finalX, finalY);

    grid[x, y] = originalValue; // allow other path checking to revisit this space.

    return paths;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the program works now however in some cases it ignores the correct cases because of the grid replacement. I do keep a backup copy of the grid that's currently being run however I don't know where to place it
ex output: https://imgur.com/guPuXt1

Comment: @Devy: Yeah, thinking about it some more, I can see how my original approach might cause problems in some cases. I updated my code to set the original value back after recursion is done, which I think should solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of doing it.

Start with a function that returns the valid neighbours of a specific location in the grid:

```
private IEnumerable<(int r, int c)> GetNeighbours(int[,] grid, (int r, int c) reference)
{
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            var neighbour = (r: reference.r + i, c: reference.c + j);

            if ((i != 0 && j != 0)
                || neighbour == reference
                || neighbour.r < 0 || neighbour.r >= grid.GetLength(0)
                || neighbour.c < 0 || neighbour.c >= grid.GetLength(1))
            {
                continue;
            }
            yield return neighbour;
        }
}
```

This returns the left, right, up, and down neighbour so long as it is in the valid grid.

Then we'll make a `public` method that triggers off the building of a path:

```
public List<(int r, int c)> RecursiveCheck(int[,] grid, (int r, int c) initial, int goal)
{
    var path = new List<(int r, int c)>(new[] { initial });
    return RecursiveCheck(grid, path, goal);
}
```

Its purpose is to take the `initial` starting point and turn that in to a `path` of one element and then it calls the true recursive function.

And here it is:

```
private List<(int r, int c)> RecursiveCheck(int[,] grid, List<(int r, int c)> path, int goal)
{
    foreach (var neighbour in GetNeighbours(grid, path.Last()))
    {
        if (!path.Contains(neighbour))
        {
            var next = path.Concat(new[] { neighbour }).ToList();
            if (grid[neighbour.r, neighbour.c] == goal)
            {
                return next;
            }
            else if (grid[neighbour.r, neighbour.c] == 0)
            {
                return RecursiveCheck(grid, next, goal);
            }
        }
    }
    return new List<(int r, int c)>();
}
```

This takes the existing path, finds all of neighbours of the last element in the path. It checks that it hasn't visited those neighbours and then builds the `next` path. It then checks if it hits the `goal`, and if so, returns the path. Otherwise if the current cell has the value `0` it then recurses to find a solution. If it can't find a solution it returns an empty path.

Here's an example usage:

```
int[,] grid = new int[3, 5]
{
    { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, 6},
};

List<(int r, int c)> path = RecursiveCheck(grid, (r: 0, c: 0), 6);

Console.WriteLine(path.Count);
```

That outputs `11` (which is the correct length to find the `6` from the top-left).